# How to debug a wordpress plugin that gives timeout

Tags: wordpress, facebook, debugging, woocommerce

I have a site that have some plugins, and one of those plugins (facebook for woocommerce) is loading until it returns a timeout error (504). I can change some constants in wp-config.php, but none of them works when I need to debug a timeout.

I tried to remove every configuration and file that I found from this plugin and then reinstall it, but the error is still there.

I tried to deactivate every other plugin, but woocommerce and the error is still there.

I looked for some debug plugins, but I only found plugins that change wp-config.php constants and do some logs at files. It is useless, I can do this.

I tried to put some "die" with messages in plugin's code, but nothing changed.

Server log just shows this:

```
x.x.x.x - - [09/Nov/2020:17:52:56 -0300] "xxxxx.com" "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-facebook HTTP/1.1" 504 160 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
```

I don't know what I can to do to debug this timeout, I've tried everything I know with the wordpress.

Comment: If the problem is a specific plugin, I think the better way is to contact the support section of that plugin.

Comment: What does this plugin do, what does it have to do with tag `facebook`?

Comment: @CBroe this is Facebook's plugin for Woocommerce, so you can advertise your products on your website and on Facebook and Instagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by asking on plugin's forum: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-page-giving-timeout-504/#post-13687667

I just needed to activate WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG flags. I discovered the line that was breaking the site and then I could properly debug and find the problem.